# PostgreSQL: Selecting N result in group by query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following SQL query that selects some results from my table:

```
select  avg(c3), count(c3), std  
from ssims where obraz = 'lena' group by std order by std
```

But I have various number of tests performed for different values of std, so it returns me something like that:

```
0.906176136363636;44;5
0.881669302325582;43;10
0.855873409090909;44;15
0.829195813953488;43;20
0.802071590909091;44;25
0.774523720930233;43;30
0.747213636363636;44;35
0.720115581395349;43;40
0.694712954545455;44;45
0.668683255813953;43;50
```

What I would like to do is to select average of constant (i.e. 20) number of results for every std value. So after such query, the second column would be 20 for each row.

How to do it? I tried limits and top, but without success

Comment: It should select 20 rows (no matter which) for each std value

Comment: If you are just looking at a random subset, and doing average, why does it matter if you're doing 20 or more rows? I can see how doing too few rows will give you an incorrect number, but too many?

Comment: It's not "too few" or "too many" case. I need to have exactly the same number for each case. It's just a good practice of scientific tests to have the same circumstances in all compared situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `PostgreSQL 8.3`:

```
SELECT  a[1] AS avg_std, a[2] AS cnt_std, std
FROM    (
        SELECT  (
                SELECT  ARRAY[AVG(c3) , COUNT(*)]
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  c3
                        FROM    ssims si
                        WHERE   obraz = 'lena'
                                AND si.std = so.std
                        ORDER BY
                                id
                        LIMIT 20
                        ) q
                ) a
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT std
                FROM    ssims
                WHERE   obraz = 'lena'
                ) so
        ) q
```

This will count both `AVG` and `COUNT` in a single index scan for each std.

Create a composite index on `(obraz, std, id)` for this to work fast.

In `PostgreSQL 8.4`:

```
SELECT  AVG(c3), COUNT(*), std
FROM    (
        SELECT  std, c3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY std ORDER BY id) AS rn
        FROM    ssims
        WHERE   obraz = 'lena'
        ) q
WHERE   rn <= 20
GROUP BY
        std
```

Comment: The 8.4 version Works pretty as a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `ssims` table has a unique id column which I have called `id` in my example you could do the following:

```
select avg(c3), count(c3), std from ssims where id in 
   (select id from ssims where obraz = 'lena' LIMIT 20)
   group by std order by std;
```

Comment: Yes, it has such column, but this doesn't work. There is an error because std must be also selected in the subquery while gouping. 
Error message:
ERROR: column "ssims.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: You can remove the group by statement from the inner select and apply to the outer select as I have now done. Depending on the results you need you could also just add id to the group by statement in the inner select.

Comment: nope, it will select only 20 elements, not 20 elements for each std value

Comment: Ah yes I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 8.4, you should be able to do that with a window function. (not sure what the std part is, but I'm sure you can add that back) Something like this (untested, so you may need to adjust some things):

```
SELECT std,avg(c3), count(c3)
FROM (
 SELECT std, c3, row_number() OVER (
  PARTITION BY std ORDER BY random())
 ) foo
WHERE row_number <= 20
GROUP BY std
ORDER BY std
```

If you don't care that you actually get a random subset, you can remove the ORDER BY random() part, and it'll give you a "almost-random" one.

Comment: Uh, I see now that the query is missing a "FROM ssims". It needs to have that before the ") foo" part. That's what I meant with "you may need to adjust some things"